# How to install Joomla on Digital Ocean (Debian 9)?

Tags: joomla-3.x, installation, server

I am a new user to Digital Ocean and I need to install Joomla to develop a small newspaper portal.

I chose Debian 9, but I don’t know how to accomplish this task.

I’ve researched here in the community and found only very old posts.

I would like to learn how to install via SSH.

Comment: Welcome to JSE. Have you tried contacting the Digital Ocean customer support? Digital Ocean is a paid service, so your question is better aimed at them.

Comment: @Fabricio Your question is about Joomla, so I find it to be on-topic here.  That said, I agree with Lodder that your first point of contact should be Digital Ocean's customer support.  Furthermore, because your question is rather Broad and seeks a multi-step walkthrough/tutorial, it is not a great fit for our site.  We aim to receive isolated issues which can be reproduced and invite relatively short/specific answers.  If you can narrow down where you are stuck,  this will help to make your question more attractive to answer.

Comment: You had given me an excellent tutorial! Now you've deleted the link. I was going to follow the tutorial today. He took an exclusive answer to make that comment useless.
Isn't this service here to help? You helped a lot, but now you gave up helping me. I'm sorry I didn't copy the link to my favorites right away.

Comment: You might want to consider developing it on a virtual machine first. Virtualbox or VMware Workstation are the software that come to mind. The process is somewhat similar to installing an OS on digital ocean. The advantage of doing this is that the server is for your eyes only. Once you are ready you can move the files etc to digitalocean. Not sure if this is the same tutorial - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mariadb-php-lamp-stack-debian9